# Java Stored proc giving an error

Tags: sql, oracle, java-stored-procedures

I am trying to create a stored proc the following way:

```
DROP procedure IF EXISTS plus1inout
/;
CREATE procedure plus1inout (IN arg int, OUT res int)
BEGIN ATOMIC
    set res = arg + 1;
END
/;
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1.
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'IF'.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1.
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'IN'. (Line 3)
```

Comment: This isn't `Sql Server` syntax

Comment: Hint:  `create or replace procedure`.

Comment: You are using Oracle syntax but error messages definetly are from Ms Sql-server. Check if you are connected to the right server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax isn't valid in sql server.

For checking the existence use `object_id` function

```
IF OBJECT_ID('plus1inout', 'P') IS NOT NULL
    DROP PROCEDURE plus1inout
```

For input parameter you don't have to mention `IN` keyword. For `OUTPUT` parameter use the keyword `OUT` at the end. Also parameters starts with `@` in `Sql Server`

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Plus1inout (@arg INT,
                             @res INT output)
AS
  BEGIN
      SET @res = @arg + 1;
  END
```

In `SQL SERVER 2016` they introduced the syntax you have used for checking the existence of a procedure

```
DROP procedure IF EXISTS plus1inout
```

Answer (score 1):

several things. That "/" is from oracle. if you want, you can use the word GO. To check for existence: you use this code:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('plus1inout', 'P') IS NOT NULL
        DROP PROC plus1inout
GO
```

Then you create the procedure.
In the creation , the parameters declaration is wrong.

```
CREATE procedure plus1inout (@arg int, @res int out)
BEGIN ATOMIC
    set @res = @arg + 1;
END;
```

Comment: also the IN in the parameter list is not sql-server. You might also mention that

Comment: How should `CREATE PROC` should look like

Comment: depends on if its oracle or sql-server or another database